# Adding user input number of rows=columns in a matrix C#

Tags: c#, matrix

i want to make user input number of rows that are equal to columns because i want a square matrix, in that im using a 3x3 matrix :

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        double[,] M = new double[3, 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        {
            double input;
            Console.Write("Insert a value :");
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
            {
                Console.Write("Insert correct value!");
            }
            Numbers.Add(int.Parse(input.ToString()));
        }
```

How i have to change my code? thank you

Comment: Look at the history of questions of this guy ) He makes SO do a homework project for him... While doing absolutely nothing by himself.

Comment: Im just studying by myself and im not doing homeworks, if those questions disturb you just do not reply thank you.

Comment: I see nothing done by you - just copy-pasting of what was done by other people.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you meaning for this:

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // use TryParse to be sure the value is correct
double[,] M = new double[n, n];
```